# Where is Flask running from on my OS X machine?

Tags: python, flask

I'm used to building my websites with PHP, and on my OS X machine I expect to have to ensure that I have my scripts living in an explicitly specified location that I define as my Apache server's document root. But when I follow the [simple instructions](http://flask.pocoo.org) for building a Flask website, I magically get a working website, with nothing at all in any of the places on my machine that serve as document roots, regardless of where I have my Flask script. This is especially confusing since I always think if deployment as involving careful duplicating the file structure of my site under document root on the deployment server's document root.

Where is Flask "running from" on my OS X machine? Where do I "put it" when I deploy it (and what to I put)?

Comment: when you pass `__name__` into the constructor of `Flask`, it uses that to set up everything in the current working directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's running from wherever you put it. You surely know where you saved the code: that's where it is.

But your mistake is in thinking that this development environment is running through Apache, or indeed has anything to do with how you'll run it in production. Neither is true. You're using a development server, the separate Werkzeug project, but that is not suitable for running in prod.

When you are ready to deploy, Flask has [full instructions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/#deployment) on how to either connect it to Apache through mod_wsgi, or set up a separate WSGI server which you'll usually connect to through a reverse proxy such as nginx.

Comment: So if I (instead) configure locally to run using Apache (through mod_wsgi) do I end up (I'll read the docs, just looking ahead) with a tree that I can deploy by simply copying to a (suitably configured) deployment Apache server (just as I do with PHP)?

Comment: Sort of, but it's a bit more complicated than that, mainly because you'll need the various dependencies - like Flask itself, and the libraries for templating and database connection, and whatever else you need. Those are typically installed outside of your code tree and need installing separately. Best practice is to use a virtualenv along with pip, which can output all your dependencies to a requirements.txt file which you then pass to pip on your server to install things there.

Answer (score 1):

Supposed you have your **main.py** under **/path/to/my_project/**, when you run the internal server `python main.py`, **Flask** is then running under your project folder.

Of course that built-in server is only good for development, when you're trying to deploy for production, normally **Gunicorn** (via wsgi app, read more [HERE](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#deploying-to-a-web-server)) or other web server is more appropriated (and advised by **Flask**) itself. And your production folder can be placed wherever you want, just like Apache PHP you may place your folder under **/var/www/** (**EDITED**: as Daniel Roseman pointed out, you may try to change this folder location for security concern), it's the same for **Flask**, that's nothing stops you placing the folder but rather have the permission set properly.
Hope this helps.

Comment: You shouldn't really recommend putting code under /var/www. Although as you say if you have permissions set up correctly it may not be a problem, it's far too easy to allow security holes - and since it's not necessary to put the code there, it's best avoided.

Comment: So the key is that I'm not using Apache at all but a different web server that's started by Flask when I run the app, correct?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I'm not suggesting placing the folder under **/var/www**, but since rax is from PHP background he's more familiar with how Apache works with PHP, that's all :) But yes, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: So (unfortunately) unlike deployment of my (Apache developed) PHP sites which simply involve copying my directory structure to the right place on a deployment server, deployment of a Flask site involves more steps (and some configuration) beyond merely copying. Correct?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, exactly, but like I said above, Apache may use so called default folder at **/var/www/**, for Flask however there's no default but all depending on your webserver, say for example if you use **Gunicorn**, then it's about how you configure **Gunicorn**'s instance to point to which folder as your default folder. You still at the end just like copy and paste your project folders to that **default** folder.

Comment: as a side note, if you prefer to Apache webserver, here's a doc you may be interested in reading [mod_wsgi(Apache) - Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/)